# I want xref-find-definitions that uses the second backend when the first backend doesn't find anything

Tags: lsp-mode, xref

I program in Haskell using `lsp-mode` with `lsp-haskell`. I need to have a working "jump to definition". `xref-find-definitions` using `lsp--xref-backend` sometimes fails to find the definition. `xref-find-definitions` using `etags--xref-backend` usually finds the definition together with other unrelated definitions. I want to have a command that runs `lsp--xref-backend` first, and if it doesn't find anything, runs `etags--xref-backend`. How do I achieve that? Simply setting `xref-backend-functions` to `'(lsp--xref-backend etags--xref-backend)` never invokes the etags backend even when the lsp backend doesn't find anything.

Comment: did you find a solution?

Comment: No, I did not find one